# Does $z \in \mathbb{C}$ exist such that $|z - i| + |z - 1| < \frac{4}{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Does $z \in \mathbb{C}$ exist such that $|z - i| + |z - 1| < \frac{4}{3}$ ?

---

My attempt: We know that $|z - 1| = |1 - z|$ so we have $|z - i| + |1 - z|$. Using the triangle inequality, we have
$$|z - i| + |1 - z|\geq |z - i + 1 - z|= |1 - i| = \sqrt{1^2 + (-1)^2} = \sqrt{2}$$

This would imply $$4/3 > |z - i| + |z - 1| \geq \sqrt{2} $$

But $$4/3 = 1.3333 < 1.414 = \sqrt{2}$$

Is this sufficient as proof ? Can I just take the numerical values of $4/3$ and $\sqrt{2}$ at the end to compare them or do I need to do something else ? Is there anything else wrong or strange in my attempt ? Did I forget or skip something ?

Comment: About the inequality, are we talking about $\mathfrak{Re}(|z-i|+|1-z|)\lt\frac43$ or do we have $|z-i|+|1-z|\lt\frac43+0i$?

Comment: @CrSb0001 The complex modulus is strictly real valued, so you only need to consider it as a real number. So essentially both of your expressions are correct. But the real part and zero imaginary part are redundant.

Comment: @CrSb0001: if I recall correctly, the absolute value forces all complex numbers to express a real magnitude, so the is no longer an imaginary component at all...

Comment: @CrSb0001 The exercise says exactly what I wrote in the title, there is no mention of real or imaginary part like you say, I honestly don’t know

Comment: @abiessu Ah, sorry about that. I'm not exactly that familiar with that type of stuff, so thanks for helping me understand that.

Comment: @wengen: for your question, imagine $z$ on a line between $1$ and $i$ (positive and negative are negotiable since these form a square around zero).  Anywhere on that line in between the two, the sum of the two distances from $z$ to each of $1,i$ will add up to the distance from $1$ to $i$, which is what your correctly-applied triangle inequality is telling you.

Comment: Your proof is fine, except your statement $4/3=1.3333$ and $1.414=\sqrt2$ which are not really true.  I would write instead $4/3=1.33... < 1.414 < \sqrt2$ to be accurate. If you're troubled by the decimal approximation, you can equivalently square both sides (as they are both positive) like so $4/3> \sqrt2 \implies 16/9 > 2 \iff 16> 18$ which is obviously false.

Comment: A shorter proof would just exhibit such a $z$.  Say, $z=i$.  (You could find this by drawing a picture as @abiessu suggests.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say at the start of your proof, "Suppose (by way of contradiction) that there exists $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z - i| + |z - 1| < \frac{4}{3}$ ", then the proof makes sense. (But you haven't said this.)

Alternatively, you can do a direct proof by starting the proof with "Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$", and also changing the line

> This would imply $$4/3 > |z - i| + |z - 1| \geq \sqrt{2} $$

to:

> This implies $$|z - i| + |z - 1| \geq \sqrt{2} > 4/3. $$